# Difference between class parametrs and injected parameters

Tags: scala, inject

It might be a very stupid question as I am learning this. 
I have a doubt regarding this,
For example, I have three classes `A`,`B` and `C`

And class `D` requires all of three classes.

So i can declare our `class D` either taking another class object as the class parameter or can inject them,

```
class D(a: A, b: B, c: C)
```

or

```
class D @Inject()(a: A, b: B, c: C)
```

They both allow me to use objects of Classes A, B and C.

What exactly is the difference between both approaches? When should we use which one?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: When you passing parameters into the constructor you have to create respective objects yourself, i.e. for each of D's parameters a, b, c you should do something like val a = new A(), val b = new B(), val c = new C() and then pass respective variables a, b, c to the D constructor.

Using @Inject allows to create and initialize dependencies by the IoC container, i.e. a, b, c would be created automagically and you no need anymore to create/initialize them (and there dependencies if any).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert but @Inject annotation is related to a dependency injection framework like Guice. Guice will initialize A, B and C if it can. IMHO the problem with most of this frameworks is that they can throw wiring exceptions at runtime (containers are a very dark world :P). Try to use, at least if you are learning, the first approach. It will help you to focus on learning language basics and don't fight with a DI framework and compiler will help you a lot. I recommend you a DI framework for a large projects.